# How to include/mark code in the middle of the text line

Tags: code

I want to include short code for in a single line that is marked by a grey background. Here is an example:

I want to include `code of this form` that is in the middle of the text.

Comment: Do you mean find the middle of a line and then mark it or just mark some text that may be in the middle ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example built from the `tcolorbox` package. You can get all relevant information and customisation options from the well detailed [manual](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}
\begin{document}
An example with the \tcboxverb{tcolorbox} package with its \tcboxverb{\tcboxverb} command from the \tcboxverb{xparse} library 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps somewhat fragile, but works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{codecolor}{black!30}
\newcommand{\codebox}[1]{%
  \colorbox{codecolor}{\ttfamily \detokenize{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

I want to include \codebox{code of this form} that is in the middle of the text.

I want to include \codebox{code_ of^ this\ form} that is in the middle of the text.

\end{document}
```